# XML Python - to SQL

Tags: python, sql, xml, lxml, pyodbc

I have a problem where I try to pass the xml I got using Python to SQL Server and I get the following error:

> Unknown object type lxml.etree._Element during describe, HY000

I am currently using the following code snippet

```
    xml = "{call procedure(?)}"
    values = (xmlInfo)
    cursor = engine.cursor()
    cursor.execute(xml, (xmlInfo))
    cursor.close()
    engine.close()
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o motivo de não estar indo para o SQL.
Faltava colocar um **"autocommit = True"** na conexão com o SQL

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details of your environment, you will *probably* need to call `lxml.tostring()` on the XML etree first to get an actual XML string:

```
cursor = engine.cursor()
cursor.execute("{call procedure(?)}", (lxml.tostring(xmlInfo),))
```

Comment: Making the mistake. '42000', [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102), Statenebt(s) could not be prepared (8180)